# Getting information of Nearby locations using geolocation

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to programming and I want to develop an application which shows list of items food, malls etc, and when user clicks on any of item it should automatically get location of user and display list of corresponding search and the search query is name of list item.

I tried to get coordinates of user using navigator.geolocation.watchPosition().

Here is what I've done with

Javascript code

```
var x=document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation()
{
    if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition);
    }
    else{
        x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position)
{
    initialize(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
}

/*getting locations nearby using google places api*/

function initialize(lat,lng) {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
        zoom: 15
    });

    var request = {
        reference: 'CnRkAAAAGnBVNFDeQoOQHzgdOpOqJNV7K9-c5IQrWFUYD9TNhUmz5-aHhfqyKH0zmAcUlkqVCrpaKcV8ZjGQKzB6GXxtzUYcP-muHafGsmW-1CwjTPBCmK43AZpAwW0FRtQDQADj3H2bzwwHVIXlQAiccm7r4xIQmjt_Oqm2FejWpBxLWs3L_RoUbharABi5FMnKnzmRL2TGju6UA4k'
    };

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: place.geometry.location
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.setContent(place.name);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });
        }
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

function wlCommonInit(){
    require([ "layers/core-web-layer", "layers/mobile-ui-layer" ], dojoInit);

    getLocation();
    initialize();
}
```

I know this may be a duplicate to a question but I didn't found anything matching my problem in the search. If there is any post which is useful for me please do reply.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you seeing any exceptions in the browser console (Firebug)?

Comment: no errors but its not displaying the nearby places

Comment: Are you testing this on an actual phone with location services enabled? Or are you doing this in an HTML5 compliant browser, again with location services enabled? Since you're using worklight, why not use: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WL.Device.Geo.html

Comment: Thanks for reply  Zarazthuztra.I'm testing this on a HTML5 browser.I will go through your link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it .its problem with my key,when i try to get details in browser it said "access denied". so,i changed google api key and tried it .Now i got the results in browser.